# Xcode failed to locate iOS Distribution Certificates

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I'm a member of the development team and the team admin sent me a distribution certificate and provisioning profile to sign the application.

Everything is good at the first stage of development process. I can export IPA and send to him.

At the second stage, after adding some new devices to provision profile he resends to me distribution certificate and provisioning profile again but I get below error when export IPA file.

[The error detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERnsF.png)

Xcode can't locate the certificates or what wrong with the certificate?

How can I fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Updated 1:
The export method is AdHoc distribution.

Updated 2:
I tried to clean all certificates and provisioning profiles. And then retried but the same error was occupied.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can imagine is that the admin generated a new distribution certificate (with another private key).

Open the Keychain Access, go to certificates, and check if the distribution certificate that he sent is there, and if there is a key associated to it (i.e. there is a dropdown with a key inside). If no key is associated, it means that your admin will have to send you the key that generated that certificate.
To do that, he must right click the key associated to it, and click Export "key name"...

Comment: Thanks! I solved this by removing all related certificate in the keychain and import the new one. But I realized that we don't need to update certificate when adding new devices to provisioning profile.